# Separate column with tidyr by last occurance of string

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a column I'd like to separate:

```
df <- tibble(
  variable = c("var_a_min", "var_ab_max", "var_abc_mean", "var_abcd_sd"),
  value = c(1,2,3,4)
)
```

The data look like this:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  variable     value
  <chr>        <dbl>
1 var_a_min        1
2 var_ab_max       2
3 var_abc_mean     3
4 var_abcd_sd      4
```

I'd like to separate the `variable` column, such that what's after the last underscore becomes the second column.

```
df %>% separate(variable, c("variable", "metric"), sep = [after last _])
```

I tried out some regex, but couldn't figure it out. The data should look like this:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  variable metric value
  <chr>    <chr>  <dbl>
1 var_a    min        1
2 var_ab   max        2
3 var_abc  mean       3
4 var_abcd sd         4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An option is `extract` to capture the characters as a group.  In the firsst capture group, it is a greedy match (`(.*)` - zero or more characters), followed by a `_` and in the second group (`([^_]+)$`), match characters that are not a `_` until the end of the string (`$`).  In this way, it make sure the first greedy match backtracks

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    extract(variable, into = c("variable", "metric"), "(.*)_([^_]+$)")
```

---

`separate` can take regex lookarounds as well, so if the prefix substring is 'var', then can make a lookaround with

```
df %>% 
  separate(variable, into = c("variable", "metric"), "(?<!var)_")
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  variable metric value
#  <chr>    <chr>  <dbl>
#1 var_a    min        1
#2 var_ab   max        2
#3 var_abc  mean       3
#4 var_abcd sd         4
```

Comment: That did it. What's the difference between `separate` and `extract`?

Comment: @broesel23  `separate` splits on the delimiter provided.  Here, it s `_`, but we specify the position of `_` by specifying that it should be not followed by 'var'.  In the `extract`, we are capturing the characters and discard those don't want to be in the output